# How to hide URL in Axios HTTP request or add security in another way?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

I'm doing a MERN stack (MongoDB, Express, React, Node) project in which I need to make a HTTP request, in a React component, to the database to get a field of a model. I'm using Axios (could use any other method) but the thing is I want to hide the URL but don't know how.

**The important thing for me is to get the "category" field and display it in the component**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import Heading from "../../common/Heading"

import "./Location.css"
import axios from 'axios'


const Location = () => {

  const [locations, setLocations] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/properties/categories'//this is what I want to hide);
      setLocations(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      <section className='location padding'>
        <div className='container'>
          <Heading title='Explore By Location' subtitle='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.' />

          <div className='content grid3 mtop'>
            {locations.map((item, index) => (
              <div className='box' key={index}>
                <img src={} alt='' />
                <div className='overlay'>
                  <h5>{}</h5>
                  <p>
                    <label>{}</label>
                    <label>{}</label>
                    <label>{}</label>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default Location
```

This code isn't finished just in case. Server is set up with Express and Mongoose as a way to interact with MongoDB.

Someone told me that they make only POST requests without URLs, send always the same JSON, then encrypt the JSON parse used in the backend in base 64 and point all requests to the same URL.

I know leaving a URL like that in the frontend isn't a good idea even though it doesn't GET any sensitive info, just don't know if when finished it'll pass the SSL certificate test.

Also my app doesn't have and use sensitive information at all and all requests are GETs to see info that is stored in DB

Comment: You _can't_ hide the URL, or any other detail of the request, from the client that's making it. It's not at all clear what problem you think you have here, so what if they look at it, what's insecure?

Comment: I need to get the "category" field to display it in the component, client doesn't even have the option to ask for the data, making a HTTP request was the fastest way I found. Also thought about getting the data and handle it in the Backend but I have no idea how to give this data to the Frontend

Comment: I am not sure why you'd like to hide the URL and I am pretty sure it's not possible. You can use some workaround like building it on the runtime piece by piece but it's not worth it. The client will have access to it anyway.

Comment: I'm a begginer in Backend and cyber-sec so I'm probably wrong on how I'm facing the situation hahaha, thanks for the answer

Comment: If you're looking for best security practices for a URL. Then look into SQL injection. There you can find more about URL vulnerabilities. like how passing params directly can be avoided etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find workarounds to generate your URL string on the runtime, **but that really does not worth the efforts**, as you'll be sending these requests from the client's browser to your backend, they can inspect the network tab and see the outgoing requests to your backend, and that's fine.

You can shift your focus, to working on having a better and more secure communication between your front-end and backend. For example:

- Use HTTPS so you encrypt your POST request bodies, if you still didn't get one, you may want to use [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) for now.
- Protect your API endpoints with authentication, rate limiting, API keys and CORS (see recommendations from [OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/)).
- Do not expose any secrets on the front-end, React does not need to know anything about your database (host, ip, username, etc). Your backend express application is your proxy to the database, and (express) should communicate in a secure way with MongoDB.

Comment: Great, will take a look to the links you posted
If you have any other recomendation for a begginer feel free to let me know

Comment: I hope that my input answered your question. For the resources I'm confident that you will find plenty of you Google for API security best practices, and for Node security checklists. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use environment variables
Use a proxy server or a backend platform as a service (BaaS)
Use a secure hosting platform

```
const API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY
```